# MySQLからデータを取り出すと文字化けします

Tags: php, mysql

MySQLのテーブルからデータを取り出すプログラムをPHPで書きましたが、文字化けしてしまいます。どなたか助けてください。

[image: corrupted characters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースファイルを書いている文字コードと、DB上の文字コードの違いのようです。
画像を見た感じでは、ソースファイルはShift-jis、DBの文字コードはUTF8ではないでしょうか。
ソースファイルを開いて、UTF8で保存しなおしてみてください。
また、HTMLヘッダやHTTPヘッダで文字コードを指定している場合は、そのcharsetも確認してみてください。

Comment: ソースファイルはutf8です。「mysql_query("set names utf8");」この部分が間違っているんでしょうか？

Comment: HTMLヘッダを修正したら直りました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ギャングスタキャット秋月  直ったなら`回答を投稿`から解決方法の自己回答  もしくは回答の左側にあるチェックマークを押して回答の承認をしてください。